# Copy and rename specific file sequentially from a pm2 list running apps

Tags: command-line, bash, copy

I want to make a bash to copy a specific file (app8000.js) in the same folder, and rename it sequentially accordingly a list of already running apps at my pm2 (app8001.js, app8002.js, app8003.js) then find "8000" inside the file and replace it for the number in the new file name like: "8004", "8005", "8006"...

To make it more clear:

1. copy the original file (e.g app8000.js)
2. find the lastest number at pm2 running apps list (e.g app8003.js)
3. rename the new file "app8004.js"
4. find specific text like "8000" inside this new file and replace all matches with "8004"
5. pm2 start this new app

Sorry for bad english
Beginner linux user, so please go easy on me :)

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello. After you post the script you have written someone may be able to point out any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your request properly but you can try that:

```
#!/bin/bash

numberOfProcess=$(find . -name 'app*' -printf x | wc -c)
newID=$((8000 + $numberOfProcess))
cp app8000.js app$newID.js
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It helped a lot. It is working, but I need a little improvement:

e.g. There is app8001.js, app8002.js, app8003.js. If i delete "app8002.js", when i run bash it tries to create "app8003.js" again instead of "app8002.js".  How can i check if it is any number available between the last one?

Thanks in advance